# I want to create or change an event on a form, dynamically, how can i do that?

Tags: delphi, events, delphi-7

i'm trying to write a taskbar for my program, and i need to add one line of code in 2 events, OnClose and OnActivate, but my program has over 100 forms, so i'd like to do it dynamically. Is there an way to do it?

The language is Delphi 7.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you explain it better? Do you mean add the same lines of code to every `OnClose` / `OnActivate` event of every form?

Comment: Yeah, i mean, i could do it manually, form by form, but that's too much work. But i want to know if a form has the OnActivate event, if it has, i'll add "another line of code" into the existing event, if not, i need to create the event and add the code. I thought about Inheritance but i don't know if there's a way to inherit at runtime.

Comment: You can't add code dynamically - but you can override the event to another handler and then call the original event handler dynamically. But for a "taskbar" this is a sloppy approach. You should instead have a base form which implements this capability, and then inherit the rest of your forms from that one. Unfortunately, this approach is much easier if you hadn't already created hundreds of forms. Now that you've already gotten this far, it will indeed be a nightmare to convert even just one form to inherit now.

Comment: Show what you've researched and tried so far. read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can make a common `TForm` descendant where you will do the common things. Then you'll descend all your forms from this common class.

Comment: @TLama That's what I'm suggesting, but with over 100 forms already made, it will be a horrible nightmare.

Comment: @Jerry, replacing e.g. `class(TForm)` with `class(TMyBaseForm)` isn't that hard.

Comment: @TLama Every attempt I've ever made has always resulted in a broken form, specifically with the dfm.

Comment: I thought about the event override, but i don't know how to do it. I'd have to know what the previous event was doing for this. There's a way to, at runtime, Inherit the previous event on a new event and add the new code?

Comment: No, you don't. 1) Obtain a copy of whatever is already assigned to the event, 2) Replace the event with your own handler, 3) When your own handler is called, make sure it also calls the original handler which you saved a copy of. Either way, you'll still have to do work on every single form across your app, because how is it to know which forms you want to do? Surely there's 1 or 2 forms which you don't want doing this...

Comment: @JerryDodge And how can i do that? Can you show me an example?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6WTXKuWm

Comment: `var Original: TNotifyEvent; begin Original:= SomeForm.OnClose; SomeForm.OnClose := NewHandler;` And then in `NewHandler` ... `if Assigned(Original) then Original(Sender);` But there will be more to this, specifically making sure it's done on every single form.

Comment: TLama has the more ideal solution though.

Comment: I'd use the inherit solution if I didn't need to go form to form making them inherit this base form. But i can't because there's already some inheritance in some forms, others don't have it and so on, it's a lot of forms. I'll see if i can manage to pull the @JerryDodge explanation. Thank you guys, i'll be back to tell if it worked out.

Comment: Do the inheritance. You'll never regret it.

Comment: Edited with solution.

Comment: I reverted the edit. Questions are for questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As TLama and David Hefferman say, inheritance is right way to do it, but sometimes pragmatism wins out over the right way. So here is a horrible Kludge that will do the job.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  VCL.Forms,
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TKludge = class
  private
    fForm: TForm;
    fOnClose: TCloseEvent;
    fOnActivate: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure fNewOnActivate( Sender : TObject );
    procedure fNewOnClose( Sender : TObject; var Action : TCloseAction );
  public
    property Form : TForm
             read fForm;
    property OnClose : TCloseEvent
             read fOnClose;
    property OnActivate : TNotifyEvent
             read fOnActivate;
    constructor Create( pForm : TForm );

  end;

  TKludges = class( TObjectList<TKludge> )
  private
    fApplication: TApplication;
    procedure SetApplication(const Value: TApplication);
  public
    property Application : TApplication
             read fApplication
             write SetApplication;
  end;


implementation

{ TKludge }

constructor TKludge.Create(pForm: TForm);
begin
  fForm := pForm;
  fOnClose := pForm.OnClose;
  pForm.OnClose := fNewOnClose;
  fOnActivate := pForm.OnActivate;
  pForm.OnActivate := fOnActivate;
end;

procedure TKludge.fNewOnActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned( fOnActivate ) then fOnActivate( Sender );
  // my extra line
end;

procedure TKludge.fNewOnClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if assigned fOnClose then fOnClose( Sender, Action );
  // my extra line
end;

{ TKludges }

procedure TKludges.SetApplication(const Value: TApplication);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  fApplication := Value;
  for i := 0 to fApplication.ComponentCount do
  begin
    if fApplication.Components[ i ] is TForm then
    begin
      Add( TKludge.Create( fApplication.Components[ i ] as TForm ));
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Create an instance of the TKludges class and pass the Application to it. For *every* form that it finds it will replace the events with new ones that call the original if it exists and put your extra lines in (just comments at the minute).

What makes it particularly horrible is the EVERY form will be affected, including ones you might not expect. But if you are sure...

Use at your own risk!

Comment: Forms don't have to be owned by Application, forms don't have to exist already, and forms don't have to descend from TForm (but TCustomForm). So I doubt this' working. When do you want to set the Application property?

Comment: @NGLN You are right on all counts, but in practice Forms are usually owned by an application are usually created before TApplication.Run and are usually descended from TForm. As I expressly said this is a kludge to deal with a very specific situation where a 'good' solution is not a viable option. This is not a pretty solution but a workable one.

Comment: Usually, forms are created on demand and not before Application.Run, except for the main form or very large often-used-and-long-time-to-load-forms perhaps. If you instead of looping through Application's components use Screen.CustomForms, then you are better of. TCustomForm is used for TCommonDialog for example. Even workable solutions can be made prettier.

Comment: @NGLN In my experience forms are not created on demand unless you explicitly invoke that i.e. the default action is to create all forms that you designed as the program starts up, and that is appropriate in this case. Forms you create visually are descended from TForm, not TCustomForm, and as far as TCommonDialog descendants is concerned I would be amazed if the programmer wanted to mess with those! So to my mind TForm is far better than TCustomForm in this case.